# Get rows in multiple tables that don't have a match in one single table

Tags: mysql

Table A has an id that tables B,C,D,E,F have a column for (a_id) which is not nullable.
But no PK/FK.

Trying to find all individual rows in tables B,C,D,E,F where a_id is a value that doesn't match any row in table A.

Examples:

Table A
| ID | Foo |
| -- | -- |
| 123 | Bar 1 |
| 124 | Bar 2 |
| 125 | Bar 3 |

Table B
| ID | A_ID |
| -- | -- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 125 |
| 3 | 999 |

Table C
| ID | A_ID |
| -- | -- |
| 4 | 124 |
| 5 | 125 |
| 6 | 888 |

Table D
| ID | A_ID |
| -- | -- |
| 7 | 124 |
| 8 | 125 |
| 9 | 777 |

Table E
| ID | A_ID |
| -- | -- |
| 10 | 124 |
| 11 | 125 |
| 12 | 666 |

Table F
| ID | A_ID |
| -- | -- |
| 13 | 124 |
| 14 | 125 |
| 15 | 555 |

I'd need one select that results in

Result

| A_ID | B_ID | C_ID | D_ID | E_ID | F_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 9 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 12 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 15 |

Comment: Added context and tables

Comment: @basha04 I did. Faking a series of entries by just listing them as a string in the statement isn't a solution

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As requested I've rewritten the statements coupling all tables into one statement using UNION.

```
    SELECT a.id
    FROM   Table A
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.rowname
                       FROM   Table B
                       WHERE  B.rowname = a.id
                       UNION SELECT C.rowname
                       FROM   Table C
                       WHERE  C.rowname = a.id
                       UNION SELECT D.rowname
                       FROM   Table D
                       WHERE  D.rowname = a.id
                       UNION SELECT E.rowname
                       FROM   Table E
                       WHERE  E.rowname = a.id
                       UNION SELECT F.rowname
                       FROM   Table F
                       WHERE  F.rowname = a.id )
```

Good day,

I am a bit new to mysql myself. However I did some research and managed to find a code solution relying on NOT EXISTS. Let me know if this approach works for you.

```
    SELECT a.id
    FROM   Table A
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.rowname
                       FROM   Table B
                       WHERE  B.rowname = a.id)
```

Comment: That only covers table A and B, ignoring the rest of the tables.

Comment: Yes this is true. You'd have to come up withj an expression that covers all of your tables, perhaps using the UNION operator.  SELECT B.rowname
                       FROM   Table B
                       WHERE  B.rowname = a.id UNION SELECT C.rowname
                       FROM   Table C
                       WHERE  C.rowname = a.id

Comment: I hope this works. Maybe there are more pretty solutions out there, I am quite new to mysql myself!

Comment: @basha04 Thanks for elaborating on this! I'll take a quick look at the demo but it definately seems helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
select a.id as "a.id", b.id as "b.id","NULL" as "c.id","NULL" as "d.id","NULL" as "e.id","NULL" as "f.id" from a right join b on a.id=b.a_id where a.id is null 
UNION ALL
select a.id,"NULL",c.id,"NULL","NULL","NULL" from a right join c on a.id=c.a_id where a.id is null 
UNION ALL
select a.id,"NULL","NULL",d.id,"NULL","NULL" from a right join d on a.id=d.a_id where a.id is null 
UNION ALL
select a.id,"NULL","NULL","NULL",e.id,"NULL" from a right join e on a.id=e.a_id where a.id is null 
UNION ALL
select a.id,"NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL",f.id from a right join f on a.id=f.a_id where a.id is null ;
```

[image]

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/20